# Application output button in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Studio to write C# and the Application Output button in the bottom right hand corner of the window has disappeared. I've had a look how to make it appear again but can't work out. Any help on turning it back on would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under **View**->**Pads**->**Application Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, I've looked there and the Application Output option isn't on the Pads menu. Nor is Package Console and Search Results.

Comment: It's in a non-standard place then; that's the only location I've ever known the Application Output pad to live.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Studio are you running and what platform?

Comment: I'm running version 5.9.2 (build 4) on MacBook Air. To be honest not entirely sure what you mean by platform. Apologies I'm a complete newbie to this setup.

Comment: Platform = Operating System. That answered my question though. I'll look through my settings.

Comment: So under `~/Library/Preferences/XamarinStudio-5.0` is a file named `EditingLayout.xml`. This seems to store the layout preferences for the ide. I hacked this and the `Application Output` menu item has vanished!

Comment: Generally these menu items are registered in MonoDevelops addin system. My guess is the CommandHandler that triggers the Application Output window is failing to load for some reason; I'll keep digging. I kinda need to get that window back now as well haha :P

Comment: I've noticed if you run a solution the Application Output pad will re-appear in the menu. Try that?